# Optional nested properties and v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that's used for *either* creating a new item *or* updating an existing item in the database. I'm initializing the item in the data as an empty object:

```
module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return { item: {} };
    },
};
```

However, I'm using `v-model` to associate a field with a nested property of `item`:

```
<input id="author" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.author">
```

This generates the warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "item.author".
```

If possible, I'd *like* to tell Vue not to worry if it can't evaluate this expression. I'd *like* to avoid explicitly declaring every property of `item` and just letting my API populate it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you could have your API pass it an array of property names, then could use $set while looping over the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.propertyNameListFromAPI.length; i++)
{
     this.item.$set(response.propertyNameListFromAPI[i], null );
}
```

OR if you have an existing item object you could iterate over its property names:

```
for (var propertyName in exampleItemObject )
{
     this.item.$set(propertyName, exampleItemObject[propertyName] );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could suppress all Vue.js logs and warnings, but not a specific warning.

```
Vue.config.silent = true
```

Comment: I was hoping more for something like `v-model="item ? item.author : null"` to prevent the error rather than suppressing it (which it'll already be in production, I believe).

Comment: Please dont actually do this. Its terrible practice to silence errors. Your supposed to *fix* them.